# Couchbase create Index given error,GSI CreateIndex() - cause: Fails to create index

Tags: couchbase, sql++

In CBQ I am tring to create a index using below query

```
CREATE INDEX isched ON reachEffect ( 
    ARRAY_SUM(ARRAY x.clicks * x.bid FOR x IN bids END) );
```

But I get the error below:

> [{"code":5000,"msg":"GSI CreateIndex() - cause: Fails to create index.
>               There is no available index service that can process this request at this
>            time. Index Service can be in bootstrap, recovery, or non-reachable.
>        Please retry the operation at a later time."},{"original_query":"CREATE INDEX 
>       isched ON reachEffect ( ARRAY_SUM(ARRAY x.clicks * x.bid FOR x IN bids END) )"}]

Comment: It sounds like there may be an issue with the Indexer service on your cluster. What version of Couchbase are you using? How many nodes do you have? How many nodes are running the indexing service? If you launch the admin UI, what do you see in the "Indexes" tab?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me, the fix was to change the default ports for Indexers. You can check Couchbase documentation, there you can find default ports and how to change them.

Couchbase documentation:
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/install/install-ports.html

Another solution could be to stop Couchbase from **Task manager -> services** and then run the following commands in the command prompt:

netstat -ano | findstr :***(couchbase default port)***
taskkill /PID ***(PID)*** /F

to kill all the processes that are running on the port that Couchbase use.